# Ajax button not working

Tags: php, ajax

So i'm trying to make a follow button in wp, and for some reason the ajax button isn't working right.
Here are the steps of what's supposed to happen

1. user clicks #followbtn
2. Ajax goes to $_POST action that = follow
3. php runs wp_set_object_terms( $user_id, $author_id, 'follow', true );
4. when that's done the function echo's "ok"
5. if the data = ok reload the page

For some reason the php isn't executing and the page isn't being reloaded.

```
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_jk-author-follow', 'jk_author_follow' );
add_action( 'wp_ajax_jk-author-follow', 'jk_author_follow' );
function jk_author_follow() {
$nonce = $_POST['nonce'];
if ( ! wp_verify_nonce( $nonce, 'ajax-nonce' ) )
    die ( 'Nope!' );

if($_POST['action'] == "follow") {

$author_id = get_the_author_meta( 'nickname' ); // get authors name    
$termId = get_term_by( 'slug', $author_id, 'follow' ); // get the term id from author
$termId = $termId->term_id;
$followers = get_objects_in_term( $termId, 'follow' ); // count followers in author term
$author_follow_count = count( $followers );

if ( is_user_logged_in() ) { // user is logged in
    $user_id = get_current_user_id(); // current user
    wp_set_object_terms( $user_id, $author_id, 'follow', true ); // Follow the author
    echo "ok"; 
   } 
  }
 }
exit;
}
```

Front end button

```
function getAuthorFollowLink( $author_id ) {
$author = get_the_author_meta( 'nickname' );
$user_ID = get_current_user_id();
$termId = get_term_by( 'slug', $author, 'follow' ); // get the term id from author
$termId = $termId->term_id;
$followers = get_objects_in_term( $termId, 'follow' ); // count followers in author term
$count = count( $followers );
$output = '<a href="#" id="followbtn">Folllow&nbsp;'.$count.'</a>';
return $output;
}
```

js

```
$(function(){
$('#followbtn').on('click', function(e){
e.preventDefault();
$('#followbtn').fadeOut(300);

$.ajax({
  url: ajax_var.url,
  type: 'post',
  data: {'action': 'follow'},
  success: function(data, status) {
    if(data == "ok") {
        location.reload();
    }
  },
  error: function(xhr, desc, err) {
    console.log(xhr);
    console.log("Details: " + desc + "\nError:" + err);
  }
   }); // end ajax call
 });
});
```

Comment: there's no such thing as an ajax button

Answer (score 0):

Try disabling this code

```
if ( ! wp_verify_nonce( $nonce, 'ajax-nonce' ) )
    die ( 'Nope!' );
```

If You know the implications. You might want to learn more https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_verify_nonce